# Next.js loads dynamic structured data slow and double for Schema.org validator

Tags: reactjs, next.js, breadcrumbs

I am using next-seo to implement dynamic structured data into my Nextjs Commerce application. However, Schema.org's validator shows me two Breadcrumb results instead of one: one with undefined and one with the proper data. It seems it crawls it once and recrawls it once the data loads. How can I get the data to load quicker or eliminate the undefined Breadcrumb version.
`<BreadcrumbJsonLd itemListElements={[ { position: 1, name:` ${activeCategory?.name}`, item:` https://example.com/c${activeCategory?.path}`, }, ]} />`

[Schema.org Validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4OdW.jpg)

It should only load one Breadcrumb result that is defined instead of two that are undefined.